# Fetch api Network request failed Expo React Native loading local json file

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, expo, fetch-api

I am trying to load a static json file locally in my expo managed app as follow.

```
useEffect(()=>{
```

getData()},['']);

```
function getData(){
```

`fetch('../Audio/AudiosObj.json',{'Content-Type':'application/json','Accept': application/json'}).then((data)=>(console.log(data)).catch((err)=>(console.log(err)) }`

After running the app I got an error with message "Network request failed".
Please what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to use fetch to get the json data.
You can simply import the json directly using import statement.

```
import AudiosObjJSON from '../Audio/AudiosObj.json';
```

Otherwise if you still want to use fetch, you have provide the headers properly like this:

```js
fetch('../Audio/AudiosObj.json',{
   headers: { 
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Accept': 'application/json'
   }
})
.then(...)
.catch(...);
```

But I will still recommend using import statement as they work fine & much more readable than doing a fetch call.

Also, the fetch implementation might not work properly after you compile the app & include all the assets as the relative path might not work.

But when using import statement, the file will be part of the bundle itself & should not cause any issue after it is compiled.

Comment: I previously work with the method you suggested but I have some promise issues then I just switched to true the fetch api.

Comment: Were you getting any error when using the import statement?
Can you share what the error message was?

Comment: I just use the import method and it works